# If NOT LIKE Then Delete Column

Tags: vba, excel

I have several values in a single cell, named 'PIDList', as such:

```
'I.A.3', 'I.A.4', 'I.O.9', 'I.U.3', 'I.U.4', 'I.U.6', 'O.D.1', 'O.D.2'
```

I'm trying to loop through columns in another sheet, and if the header is not in the list above, delete the column.

```
'Find the last used column in a Row: row 1 in this example
Dim LastCol As Integer
With ActiveSheet
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

Dim lColumn As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lColumn = LastCol
For iCntr = lColumn To 1 Step -1
    If Not Cells(1, iCntr).Value Like "*" & PIDList & "*" And Cells(1, iCntr).Value <> "Delta" And Not Cells(1, iCntr).Value <> "CloseBal" _
        And Not Cells(1, iCntr).Value <> "Totals" And Not Cells(1, iCntr).Value <> "DESC1" And Not Cells(1, iCntr).Value <> "AsOfDate" Then
        Columns(iCntr).Delete
    End If
    Debug.Print Cells(1, iCntr).Value
Next
```

In the column, I have data like this:

```
I.A.3   I.A.4   I.O.9   I.U.3   I.U.4   I.U.6   O.D.1   O.D.2   O.D.3   O.D.4   O.D.5   O.D.6
```

It doesn't delete any columns if the Not...Like is true.  I tried it with and without the quotes; same result.  Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: I think you have it backwards `Not  PIDList Like "*" & Cells(1, iCntr).Value & "*"`

Comment: Ok, I just tried that.  It still deletes zero columns.  In the scenario I am looking at now, 10 columns should be deleted.

Comment: What does the PIDList contain? is that a named range of the cell where you are storing the values?

Comment: Yes, yes, that is named 'PIDList'.  I guess I dind't clarify that at first.  I just updated my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach would be something like, this will delete any column that doesn't match the values in the array:

```
Sub foo()
Dim iCntr As Long
Dim val As String
Dim PIDList() As Variant
Dim LastCol As Long
PIDList = Array("I.A.3", "I.A.4", "I.O.9", "I.U.3", "I.U.4", "I.U.6", "O.D.1", "O.D.2", "Delta", "CloseBal", "Totals", "DESC1", "AsOfDate") 'add all values to keep to this array
LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For iCntr = LastCol To 1 Step -1
    val = "Not Found" 'set variable as not found
    currentcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, iCntr).Value 'get the value of the column header for comparison
    For x = LBound(PIDList) To UBound(PIDList)
    If currentcol = PIDList(x) Then 'loop through array to see if match is found
        val = "Found"
    End If
    Next x
    If val <> "Found" Then 'if match is not found then delete
        ActiveSheet.Columns(iCntr).EntireColumn.Delete
        val = "" 'reset variable for next loop
    End If
Next iCntr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, your conditional clause is of the form

```
if (A) and (B) and (C) and (D) then
```

if any of A,B,C, or D is false, then the delete is not executed.

Some of your conditions are of the form

```
And Not Cells(1, iCntr).Value <> "CloseBal"
And Not Cells(1, iCntr).Value <> "Totals"
```

which can be translated as

```
And Cells(1, iCntr).Value = "CloseBal"
And Cells(1, iCntr).Value = "Totals"
```

One of these conditions will surely be false.

So I would think the entire clause is guaranteed to be false, which would imply no columns ever get deleted. Is that not the case ?

Answer (score 1):

First, lets clarify what you want. As I understand, you want to delete column if it **does not** contain ANY of listed headers.

Have `"*"` AND `PIDList`  AND `CloseBal` AND `Totals` as header of one column is illogic. Therefore, having `"AND"` in `IF` statement makes the clause false. Try to use `"OR"`.

Also, try backwards:

```
If header = "*" OR header = PIDList OR header = CloseBal OR header = Totals
then print "header match"
else
delete column
End if
```

*having `NOT` and `'<>'` means `NOT NOTEQUAL TO`, that is `'IS EQUAL TO'`. That makes your clause to work vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess you gotta do it with 2 IF statements:

```
    If Not PIDList Like "*" & Cells(1, iCntr).Value & "*" Then
        If Cells(1, iCntr).Value <> "Delta" And _
            Cells(1, iCntr).Value <> "CloseBal" And _
            Cells(1, iCntr).Value <> "Totals" And _
            Cells(1, iCntr).Value <> "DESC1" And _
            Cells(1, iCntr).Value <> "ASOFDATE" Then
                Columns(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
```

That works for me.